# WPF font scaling

Tags: wpf, user-interface, scaling, font-size

I have a WPF application where the user interface should be scaled so that it should become larger if the windows is made larger. In one of the dialogs, I need to present a list of items to a user and the user should click one of them. The list will contain from 1 to around 15-20 items. I want the font size for each individual item to be as big as the font size for the other items in the list, but at the same time I want the font size to increase if the window is made larger.

At the moment, my test code looks like below.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    Title="Window1" Height="480" Width="640">


    <ScrollViewer>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30*" MinHeight="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30*" MinHeight="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30*" MinHeight="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" MaxHeight="100"><Viewbox><TextBlock>T</TextBlock></Viewbox></Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="100"><Viewbox><TextBlock>Test</TextBlock></Viewbox></Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" MaxHeight="100"><Viewbox><TextBlock>Test Longer String</TextBlock></Viewbox></Button>

        </Grid>

    </ScrollViewer>

</Window>
```

If the application is started and the Window is made wide, everything looks OK. If the window width is decreased, the font size of the text `Test Longer String` is made smaller, but the font size for `T` and `Test` remains the same. I do understand why this happens - the viewbox will scale the contents to its maximum size. What I want to know is what method I should use to solve this problem.

I don't want to give the controls specific font sizes because some people will run this on low-resolution screens such as 640x480 and others will use larger widescreens.

**EDIT:**

I've tried to modify my code to the following:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Viewbox>
        <ItemsControl>
            <Button>Test 2</Button>
            <Button>Test 3</Button>
            <Button>Test 4 afdsfdsa fds afdsaf</Button>
            <Button>Test 5</Button>
            <Button>Test 5</Button>
            <Button>Test 5</Button>
            <Button>Test 5</Button>
            <Button>Test 5</Button>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Viewbox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But with the size of the button borders are increased as well, so on large screens, the button borders become a centimeter wide.

Comment: works fine for me though :/ https://i.imgur.com/GXo14Vb.gifv

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Render your text items like you would do it any other time:

- `TextBlock`s contained in an 'ItemsControl'?
- `ListBox`?

Place the whole shebang into a `ViewBox` and set it to scale appropriate to your needs. Look for Horizontal, Vertical or combined scaling properties.

Comment: I've updated my post. See under "Edit". In short, if I use a TextBlock rather than a Button, I loose the "Button"-user interface (click-effect and so on). If I use a Button and place that inside of a Viewbox, the entire button - including its border - will be resized. I don't want a 1cm button border just because the program is maximized.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround might help:

```
    <ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*" MinHeight="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*" MinHeight="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30*" MinHeight="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="0" MaxHeight="100">
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock Width="{Binding ElementName=tbLonger,Path=ActualWidth}">T</TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="100">
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock Width="{Binding ElementName=tbLonger,Path=ActualWidth}">Test</TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" MaxHeight="100">
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock Name="tbLonger">Test Longer String</TextBlock>
            </Viewbox>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The key is to set all textblocks the same width. In this case they all follow the longest textblock through binding.

Comment: I believe OP's code doesnt have a problem with the width of the buttons, they are all the same length when the window becomes smaller, but he wants the fontsize to be the same (or thats what I imply). So, the binding should be with the fontsize of the longest text.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make an resolution independent application and made it with this answer here:
[tips on developing resolution independent application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193339/tips-on-developing-resolution-independent-application)

with that your application is scaling (or zooming), depending on the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the FontSize to change then bind it to your MainWindow ActualWidth (say) and use a converter to scale:

```
<Window.FontSize>
    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" ConverterParameter="20">
        <Binding.Converter>
            <local:ScaleConverter />
        </Binding.Converter>
    </Binding>
</Window.FontSize>
```

The converter parameter is how you set the font size at some arbitrary width size (1000 pixels, say), which your converter will then also take into account:

```
internal class ScaleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Double.Parse(parameter.ToString()) * (double)value / 1000;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is probably to construct a decorator to do the job.  You might call it "VerticalStretchDecorator" or something like that.

Here is how it would be used:

```
<UniformGrid Rows="3" MaxHeight="300">
  <Button>
    <my:VerticalStretchDecorator>
      <TextBlock>T</TextBlock>
    </my:VerticalStretchDecorator>
  </Button> 
  <Button>
    <my:VerticalStretchDecorator>
      <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
    </my:VerticalStretchDecorator>
  </Button> 
  <Button>
    <my:VerticalStretchDecorator>
      <TextBlock>Test Longer String</TextBlock>
    </my:VerticalStretchDecorator>
  </Button>
</UniformGrid>
```

I used `UniformGrid` instead of `Grid`, but it would work the same way with `Grid`.

It would be implemented something like this:

```
public class VerticalStretchDecorator : Decorator
{
  protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
  {
    var desired = base.Measure(constraint);
    if(desired.Height > constraint.Height || desired.Height==0)
      LayoutTransform = null;
    else
    {
      var scale = constraint.Height / desired.Height;
      LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale); // Stretch in both directions
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile whatsoever.  Measure() returns void and there is no return value from MeasureOverride()